# Javascript location.href to mailto triggers a GET HTTP that gets canceled in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mailto

I have a button that triggers the following javascript function:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var mail = 'mailto:contact@test.com';
    location.href = mail;
};
```

In Chrome, this function triggers an HTTP GET to 'mailto:contact@test.com', but the HTTP GET has a 'canceled' status in the Inspect Element Network tab, and the email client is not opened.

In IE, the email client also does not get opened.

How can I get the email client to open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me. But you can try this

```
function sendEmail() {
    var mail = 'mailto:contact@test.com';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = mail;
    document.body.appendChild(a); // Add to the DOM
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a); // Remove it back
};
```

Comment: I tried your function but get the same 'canceled' from Chrome.

Comment: Have you configured the default mail client? It also happens when the proper URI handler is not found in the OS

Comment: Yes, it was a problem of the default email client not configured. Thank you very much.

Comment: In some situations (until now I can't figure out when and when not) I run in the same problem and Chrome ignores the location.href = "mailto:foo@bar.baz". @Салман: Your solution fixed my problem with Chrome (v39), but unfortunately it doesn't work with Firefox (v35)  and IE11. Any thought on how to fix this except of a browser depending switch?

Comment: @ischas See updated code, FF doesn't honor anchor if it hasn't been added to the DOM. So You could add it, simulate the `click` and remove it back.