# Handling mailto: status of 'canceled'

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mailto

I'm using a standard mailto: hyperlink on a page:

```
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">test</a>
```

Which works fine except where someone doesn't have their email configured, like users that only use web-based gmail. When they click the link, nothing happens. However, in the network tab of Chrome Dev tools, I can see that the request fails - "mailto:test@test.com" shows up red with a status of "(canceled)".

I'd like to handle this specific case/event with JavaScript, and looking for ideas on how to detect mailto's with status "(canceled)".  I have a server-side fallback, but I'd rather use the mailto: link when it works.

Comment: I suspect Chrome's dummy network event is just an artifact of developer tools. This pseudo-protocol has never been standardised and there's definitively no network transmission involved and, if there is (in Firefox you can configure some web based email services), it's probably something internal to the browser. Whatever, it's a good question.

Comment: Huh?... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068

Comment: I get the same "canceled" status even with my mail client setup, and with the Outlook window successfully opening for what that's worth. There's a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039988/google-chrome-mailto-status-canceled

Comment: I don't love this, but there does appear to be a hacky way of guessing if a mail client was opened https://www.uncinc.nl/articles/dealing-with-mailto-links-if-no-mail-client-is-available

Comment: Thanks for the help - I guess the answer is to go server-side if you need to support absolutely everyone.

Comment: Yeah. I think Chrome still only works out of the box if Gmail is their configured mail client. That may not be true anymore, but there is plenty of room for configuration errors.